# Succinctly return a pointer to an interface of a literal in Go

Tags: go

Is there a more succinct of casting a literal into an empty interface? A lot of the relevant community issues are about coercing an interface to a literal but not vice versa.

Looking for something of the form:

```
func pointerInterfaceOf(in interface{}) *interface{} {
    return &in
}
```

I have tried

```
&reflect.ValueOf(in).Interface() // Compiler error
```

But that is a compiler error.

Comment: It is rare to use pointers to interfaces in Go and even more rare to return a pointer to an interface from a function.  If you describe the larger problem that you are trying to solve, we might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: @XyMcXface what you say makes sense.  I'm not sure that the pointer is necessary anymore.

Comment: Agreed -- I can't see any case where this is actually necessary. If you have a function that accepts `interface{}`, or a variable of type `interface{}`, you can pass/assign whatever it is that you have, and it will get wrapped at the appropriate moment without any need for a cast.

Answer (score 2):

If the reflect value is a `*interface{}`, then use:

```
 return reflect.Value(in).Interface().(*interface{})
```

If the reflect value is not an pointer to an interface, then the shortest code is:

```
 x := reflect.ValueOf(in).Interface()
 return &x
```

The application cannot use `&reflect.ValueOf(in).Interface()` because the return value from a function is not [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast something to `interface{}`, just use the normal casting syntax:

```
interface{}(whatever)
```